# How to incorporate both integration and unit testing in one test file using Cypress

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, integration-testing, cypress

I'm looking for best practices for setting up unit and integration tests using cypress for my react application. I wanted to know if we can combine both integration and unit testing(component based testing) in a single file. Or is there any better approach anyone can provide if we want to implement both IT and UT for our application using Cypress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure *why* you want to have both in the same file, for me that would just lead to a lot of confusing tests. It would also mean that you would be executing your unit and integration tests at the same time, I think it would be better to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [cypress-react-unit-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test) to test the components, then the answer is no - it specifically prohibits using `cy.visit()` which you would need for the integration tests.

See [no-visit](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test/blob/main/cypress/component/basic/no-visit/spec.js)

```
describe('Trying to use cy.visit in component spec', () => {
  it('throws an error', () => {
    // https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test/issues/286
    expect(() => {
      cy.visit('index.html')
    }).to.throw
  })
})
```

and [src](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test/blob/2d1f758e040869de4ad29b660f7b181e5e07e48a/lib/hooks.ts#L6)

```
// When running component specs, we cannot allow "cy.visit"
// because it will wipe out our preparation work, and does not make much sense
// thus we overwrite "cy.visit" to throw an error
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (visit, ...args: any[]) => {
  if (isComponentSpec()) {
    throw new Error(
      'cy.visit from a component spec is not allowed\n' +
        'see https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test/issues/286',
    )
  } else {
    // allow regular visit to proceed
    return visit(...args)
  }
})
```

---

The Cypress component testing plugin presents nicely in the Cypress runner, for example with this cypress.json and the component tests along side the source

```
{
  "experimentalComponentTesting": true,
  "componentFolder": "src/components",
  "testFiles": ["**/*.test.js", "**/*.spec.js"]
}
```

the tests present as

```
INTEGRATION TESTS
  layout-integration.spec.js
COMPONENT TESTS
  layout
    layout-component.test.js
    another-component.test.js
```

---

As a trade-off, you can filter to tests for a certain feature in `package.json` (note the internal double-quotes are escaped with `\`)

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "cy:open": "cypress open",
  "cy:open:layout": "cypress open --config \"testFiles=\"**/layout-*.js\"\" ",
  "cy:run:layout": "cypress run --spec \"**/layout-*.js\" "
},
```

so when running `yarn cy:open:layout` only the layout tests are opened

```
INTEGRATION TESTS
  layout-integration.spec.js
COMPONENT TESTS
  layout
    layout-component.test.js
```

Sadly, the "run all specs" button skips the component tests.

When running `yarn cy:run:layout` all the layout tests (integration and component) are run together.

Comment: is there a possibility to run only the tests that are in `components` folder from cypress folder and to get the test coverage only for these tests?

Comment: could you take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71979723/react-js-and-cypress-coverage-report .